# Google Map Overlay Icon disappears at certain zoom level

Tags: firefox, google-maps, overlay-icon-disappear

I notice that Firefox 3 demonstrates this problem. I put down an overlay icon and play around with the map zoom. At certain zoom level, I found that the icon disappears for some unknown reason.

Zooming out brings back the icon. Or during the disappearance, I click on the Google Map and it will somehow trigger to bring back the icon.

I suspect it has something to do with the event triggering. Internet Explorer doesn't demonstrate the same problem though.

Any advice? Like how to trigger update event on Firefox?

Comment: Is this a programming problem?

Comment: Can you provide a simple example that reproduces the problem? Have you made sure you're using the latest version of the maps API?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `optimized: false` when creating the marker.